# Priority increase when I look into task manager

Tags: windows, task-manager

This is my observation, in Windows many times when we start any application, it won't start but process name gets added in task manager. When I click on it or try to end process, it immediately gets started. Does this happen, or it is just coincidence for me.

Does trying to end process increases its priority?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: confirmation- this happens to me too with some processes. Can't remember which ones, but I have definitely seen the behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to kill a process has nothing to do with its priority.
P.S. You can set priority to a process via right click one the process > set priority.

Comment: I know that but what about my incidence with Task Manager.

Comment: Total coincidence.

Comment: @manthan129: I don't think so. I have found other people also have same experience.

Comment: Think about it. Why should it influence the priority? It does not make sense. It can be something else though.

Comment: When I try to do something with process with Task Manager, may be it will become high priority process (somehow). And, just saying, in operating system, things are not always 'how' we think. May be I am wrong, but I am accepting answer on facts and not on guessing.

Comment: Since nobody except MS has the source code of Windows, I won't be able to tell for sure. But it is illogical from MS to make a feature like that. However, this phenomenon could be a result of something else. One reason I can think of is the fact that the CPU is able to do one action at a time (per core), and it has the actions order in the cache memory. Maybe launching the Task Manager somehow changes the order of the actions, but I can 99.9% guarantee that it's a **side effect** of something else, it's not intended.

Comment: I was glad to help. If you like my answer, click the V in the left. I also recommend reading the [sort intro](http://superuser.com/about) of the site.

Comment: I like to upvote, but I lack that much reputation points, and if I do not get more suitable answer, sure I will click that button.